# RxJava not calling subscribe() but still working. How is that possible?

Tags: java-8, rx-java2

I'm working with RxJava and Retrofit to consumes different endpoints. I'm working with a couple of microservices and all of them make use of RxJava and Retrofit to consume other services.

I don't have experience working with Observables so I'm checking some examples on internet to learn how to use it and also to create a couple of services on my own. I saw that method subscribe() is always used. Something like this:

```
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private MovieDetail movieDetail;

    public Observable<Movies> observe() {
    allMoviesClientRetrofit
                        .getMovies()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Movies>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Movies movies) {
                    allMovies = movies;

            });
```

In the services of my work, I've searched everywhere and subscribe() is never used but everything is working correctly. How is that possible?

As you can see, in that example I need to return an Observable to keep my personal code aligned with I have in my work but if I use the subscribe() method, it returns a Subscription object and that doesn't work.

This is part of the code of my work where you can see that subscribe() is never called but it works

```
@GetMapping(
        value = "/something",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
public Single<ResponseEntity<Something>> getSomething() {


    return retrieveSomethingFactory
                    .observe()
                    .toSingle()
                    .map(something -> {
                        return ResponseEntity
                                .status(httpStatus)
                                .body(something);
                    });


class retrieveSomethingFactoryImpl implements retrieveSomethingFactory

@Override
public Observable<Something> observe() {
    return Observable
        .defer(() -> {
            Observable<Something1> something1 = retrieveSomething1Factory
                        .call(link) // Retrofit call
                        .observe()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation());

            Observable<Something2> something2 = retrieveSomething1Factory
                        .call(link) // Retrofit call
                        .observe()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation()); 

            return Observable
                        .zip(something1, something2.toList(), (something1, something2) -> {

                            ....
                            ....
                            ....        

                            return something;
                        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Observable returned from your `retrieveSomethingFactory.observe()` call seems to be a hot observable, meaning it will emit items irrespective of whether it is subscribed to or not. You can read a good article about cold and hot observables [here](https://medium.com/@mohitsharma_16765/rxsubjects-cold-and-hot-observables-connectableobservable-6ab0f3020876).

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to realize if it's a hot observable.  Why do you think it is?

Comment: It's all described in the article I linked. But basically check the retrieveSomethingFactoryImpl and see if it returns either a `ConnectableObservable` or a `Subject`. Those classes contain logic which will emit items even if there are no subscriptions (Observers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i went through the code deeper and I could see a cold Observable is used. They implements Observable.Operator<Object, Object>, override method call() and inside this method return a new subscriber where is overriding methods onCompleted(), onError() and onError(), so I understand how it works now. Thanks